# Moving up/down on autocomplete selection box without arrow keys

Tags: autocompletion

I'm currently using vim on VSCode (with the *vscodevim* extension). When VSCode serves me some autocomplete options, I always have to use the arrow keys <kbd>↓</kbd> and <kbd>↑</kbd>, which are a bit of a stretch.

Is there a way to cycle through the autocomplete options without having to stretch to the arrow keys?

Comment: Note that the solution you shared is also the built-in behavior for "real" (n)vim editors.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd> to move up.
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>n</kbd> to move down.

Furthermore, these keybindings are not special to *vscodevim*, but are standard to most vim editors.